# Given a decimal value, find the decimal value rounded to 4 decimal places that when multiplied with a specific number gives a whole number

Tags: calculus

Given I have two numbers, when I divide these numbers and I get a decimal number with more than 4 decimal places. How do I find the nearest decimal that when multiplied by the divisor gives me a whole number?
For example:

3625 / 5122 = 0.7077313549

Rounded to 4 decimal places gives me 0.7077

5122 * 0.7077 = 3624.8394

How do I find a decimal number closest to 0.7077 that when multiplied by 5122, gives as result a whole number that is closest to 3625?

EDIT:
Some other examples that I can think off are:

100 / 300 = 0.3333333333

300 * 0.3300 = 99

115 / 550 = 0.20909090909

550 * 0.2200 = 121

Answer (score 1):

Added an Addendum to respond to the comment question of moleculezz

---

$5122=2×13×197.~$

So, given any real number  $~A~$,  integer or not,

if  $~5122×A = B,~$  where  $~B~$  is an integer,

then you must have that  $~A = \dfrac{N}{D},~$

where  $~N~$  is an integer and

$~D=1,~$  or  $~D = ~$  some combination of the three factors  $~2,13,197.$

---

The only prime factors of $~10~$ are $~2~$ and $~5.~$

Given any other prime number (e.g. $~3$)

the decimal expansion of its reciprocal (i.e. $~\dfrac{1}{3}~$) will have an infinite number of decimal places.

So, if you were trying to find a decimal expression $~A,~$ that was not an integer, but that only had a finite number of decimal places,

such that that $~3 \times A = B = ~$ an integer, then you would be *out of luck*.

This holds because if $~B~$ is an integer, then $~\dfrac{B}{3} = A~$ will either be an integer, or it will have a decimal expression with an infinite number of decimal places.

---

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

The original question was:

> How do I find the nearest decimal that when multiplied by the divisor gives me a whole number? For example:

> 3625 / 5122 = 0.7077313549

The new comment question:

> About the 1/3. For example 100 / 300. Taking a guess as to the closest would be 300 * 0.32 = 96.

That's a good catch.  I didn't think of this.  If the divisor happens to be any multiple of $~10,~$ then you can set $~A = \dfrac{N}{10},~$ where  $~N~$ is any integer.  This implies that $~A~$ is expressible by a finite decimal expression, and that the product of the divisor (a multiple of 10) and $~A~$ will be an integer.

The original problem specified a divisor of $~5122.~$ This divisor is not a multiple of $~10,~$ so that approach won't work with the $~5122~$ divisor.

Notice that there is a difference in searching for a finite decimal $A$, such that $~3A~$ is an integer versus $~30A~$ being an integer.

In the original problem, where you were looking for a finite decimal $~A~$ to be multiplied by $~5122~$ to get an integer product near $~3625,~$ you could change the problem so that the dividend is $~36250~$ and the divisor is $~51220.$

Then, you have that $~51220 \times 0.7 = 35854.$

Or, you could change the dividend to $~362500,~$ and the divisor to $~512200,~$ so that $~512200 \times 0.71 = 363662,~$ and so on.

Comment: Maybe I'm explaining incorrectly. But I give an example:
5122 * 0.5000 = 2561
This gives me a whole number, but this is very far from 0.7707. What I want to know is if there is another fraction closer to 0.7077 that when multiplied by 5122 gives a whole number closer to 3625

Comment: @moleculezz Read my answer more carefully.  $~2561~$ can itself be expressed as $~\dfrac{N}{D},~$ where $~N = 5122,~$ and $~D = 2.~$  Your decimal expression $~0.5~$ happens to equal $~\dfrac{1}{2}.~$  Of the $~3~$ prime factors of $~5122,~$ you have that $~2~$ is the only one that is also a prime factor of $~10.$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that great at math. But if 0.5000 is the closest decimal that when multiplied by 5122 gives me a whole number.. then that's my answer is it not? My point is that I want to know which decimal number is the closest. In this case, if 0.5000 is, then, that's my answer.

Comment: @moleculezz Yes, that's right.

Comment: About the 1/3. For example 100 / 300. Taking a guess as to the closest would be 300 * 0.32 = 96

Comment: @moleculezz See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the closest you can get of the wanted number will happen when you use all the algarisms.

In this example you gave, $\frac{3125}{5122}$, you'll never be able to use all algarisms, because it has infinite.

However, you may plug $0.7077313549 \cdot 5122$ in your calculator and get 3625, but it will only be approximation of your calculator.

If you do this calculation by hand (or just plug on another calculator) you will see different results.

In fact, $0.7077313549$ is already a approximation, so, some aprroximations may result a little less than $3625$ and some others a little more.